# Strange Load error message when trying to load an old save?

Tags: xbox-360, the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

Today I decided to play Morrowind after a long break from the game. Strangely, a save that was working properly last I checked gave me a message saying "Unable to load save game. Press a to continue." Trying to load it again crashes the Xbox. I am playing the Game of the Year edition, with no mods on Xbox 360. I searched , but no site had any specific nor helpful information.

Comment: The file may be corrupted or incompatible with patches issued to the XBox itself.   If it does load eventually and everyone tells you to look to the sky and your health meter starts draining, though, that's a different thing entirely....

Comment: I was thinking it was corrupt, since I never updated the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your save is corrupted. I recommend deleting the save file and then reinstalling the game as the game can still act a little wonky even with the corrupted save deleted.

Comment: Thanks... I had deleted it, reset the console, and picked up at an earlier save. Game works fine.